# FTP using Apache commons not working - Error: 550 Dataset not found (FTPid that i am using is getting appended to filename)

Tags: java, linux, ftp, ibm-midrange, apache-commons-net

I am trying to ftp the file from Linux VM to an AS400 server. I was able to login to server in passive mode but when trying to use the STOR command to upload the file getting below error:

```
STOR XX.YY600040.XXXZZZXXX        
**550 Dataset not found, DSN=FTPID.XX.YY600040.XXXZZZXXX**
```

Not sure why the ftpid that i am using is getting prefixed to the filename. Is there any way to avoid it?
Below is the sample code that i am using:

```
private static String sendFTPFile(String fileName) throws Exception {
        StringBuffer ftpMessage = new StringBuffer();
        if (SHOW_DEBUG) ftpMessage.append("<ul>");
        FTPClient ftp = null;
        
        try {
            String server = "****";
            String username = "****";
            String password = "XXXXX";
            String hostDir = "";
            String localFileName = fileName;
            String localFilePath = "***/**/*";
            
            boolean binaryTransfer = false, error = false;
            
            FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient();
            ftp.addProtocolCommandListener(new PrintCommandListener(
                                               new PrintWriter(System.out)));
          
            int reply;
                ftp.connect(server)
                
                // After connection attempt, you should check the reply code to verify
                // success.
                reply = ftp.getReplyCode();

                if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply))
                {
                    ftp.disconnect();
                    error = true;
                }
            
          if(!error) {
                
                    if (!ftp.login(username, password))
                    {
                        ftp.logout();
                        error = true;
                    }
             if(!error) {
                    if (binaryTransfer)
                        ftp.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

                    // Use passive mode as default 
                    ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();
                    InputStream input;
                    input = new FileInputStream(localFilePath+localFileName);
                    boolean ftpSuccess = ftp.storeFile(hostDir+localFileName, input);
                    input.close();
                       
                    if (!ftpSuccess) {
                        throw new Exception("File ftp error");
                    }else {
                        if (SHOW_DEBUG) ftpMessage.append("<li>isFtpSuccess()...success").append("</li>");
                    }
                    
                    ftp.logout();
                    if (SHOW_DEBUG) ftpMessage.append("<li>ftp.logout()...success").append("</li>");
                    
             }
        }    
                 
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Exception occur while transfering file using ftp"+ ex.toString());
            throw new Exception(ftpMessage.toString(), ex);
        }
        finally {
            if (ftp!=null && ftp.isConnected())
            {
                try
                {
                    ftp.disconnect();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    System.out.println("Exception occur while transfering file using ftp"+ e.toString());
                    throw new Exception(ftpMessage.toString(), e);
                }
            }
        
            if (SHOW_DEBUG) ftpMessage.append("</ul>");
        }
        return ftpMessage.toString();
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, but  StackOverflow is dedicated to helping solve programming code problems.  Your Q **may be**  more appropriate for [su]  , but read their help section regarding on-topic questions . Given your AS400 requirement, you may find better support on the IBM website. 
AND please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Comment: Anyplace you post a question, you'll do better if you include the actual code you are using and the exact text of any error messages that are generated. Of course you should change any personally or corporately identifiable information to placeholder strings. Good luck.

Comment: I tried to look for help on IBM site could not find any solution there. Added the sample code. Thanks a lot for your suggestions..

Comment: Also i have shared the exact error message that i am getting.. Just masked some details related to corporate

Comment: Add a tag to your Q to indicate the programming language. But first, get it to work using command line terminals, would be my advice. 10 years ago I worked (slightly) with mainframes (via unix/aix/linux) and found an IBM support forum where there were really good answers for this sort of thing. It wasn't completely obvious, but it was sponsored by IBM. Sorry I can't give you better info on that. Good luck!

Comment: And my comment about actual code and error messages was rather generic. I looked again and realized you had included real error messages. Sorry about that. Glad you have added your code, but again, I would get it to work from a simple client first. ++ for improving your Q. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks @shellter for you comments and help. I tried on terminal and getting same 550 error there as well.

Comment: I know ftp has a bunch of extra commands, but I don't know what STOR does. Did you try `GET`? Good lcuk.

Comment: err, make that `PUT` or `MPUT`. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some more debugging on doing ftp from linux to as400. And when doing pwd after logging to ftp server its giving message as:
**ftp> pwd

257 "'FTPID.'" is current prefix**

And thinking how to remove that prefix so i ran the below command got output as no prefix defined:

**ftp> cd ..

200 "" no prefix defined**

And after that when i uploaded the file using put command it was uploaded successfully. So i did some research on how to go back one directory using Apache commons.net api's that i am using and found the CDUP method.

When i ran the FTPClient.cdup() method before uploading the file. I was able to successfully FTP the file from java code as well.

```
ftp.cdup();
input = new FileInputStream(localFilePath+localFileName);
boolean ftpSuccess = ftp.storeFile(hostDir+localFileName, input);
```

Comment: The best answers to questions are the ones we figure out ourselves! Good show and good luck!